# Google Analytics w3wp.exe?

Tags: google-analytics

In this [link](http://goo.gl/X8bGM) Google defines a Visit.  The key part that interests me now, is this:  "If a user is inactive on your site for 30 minutes or more, any future activity will be attributed to a new session."

Would an idle user (e.g. an employee whose PC is left on over the weekend) record "activity" as a result of the w3wp.exe process recycling?

Our site caching model refreshes every 30 minutes. Could this trigger "activity" for an idle user?

I've asked this on the [Google Analytics forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=5eb23a25c943cac4&hl=en&fid=5eb23a25c943cac40004b2e14ea6cf42) a week ago and no response.

Answer (score 4):

Please note, I'm assuming we are talking about a browser/web based application.

The w3wp.exe process recycle should have no effect on external clients. This only affects things server side. The browser would need to initiate a request in order for activity to be logged in Analytics.

Are you using ASP.NET output caching or equivalent? If so, keep in mind this is the caching of the HTML, it does not actually render and process the HTML. So JavaScript does not execute from a server side page caching mechanism.

The only thing I can think of that might cause Google Analytics activity without user interaction would be a page that had some sort of page refresh timer built into it using a meta tag or triggered through JavaScript.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Nathan!  We added an IP filter in C# to remove employee traffic from GA.  The traffic went down way more than we thought.  The pundits point to the weekend traffic being down (since employees don't surf on the weekend) to say that the IP filter is filtering more than employee traffic.  I was trying to explain why an idol employee PC w/ browser open to our site, might count as traffic on the weekend.  I'm aware of GA's custom filters, but we've been unimpressed with their reliability.

Comment: Not been on this forum long enough to give you a Vote Up.  I would if I could. I live on StackOverflow mostly.

Comment: I'd recommend trying to use Google Analytics filters by IP. I've used it successfully for years. If you don't filter in your code and open it up again, I'd suggest you create an Analytics profile that includes all traffic, a profile that excludes the company IP addresses, and a profile that only includes company IP addresseses. This might shed some light on the traffic. On the job we have a separate profile for all, internal only, and external only traffic. Hope this helps :-)